# How to share photos, folders etc. within dropbox programmatically? (iOS)

Tags: ios, share, dropbox

Is it possible to create a shared folder by myself with dropbox SDK? Or just share a link of one file to someone, and then that someone could get this sharing notification programmatically with dropbox api?

I want to make a small app for photos sharing, for example, A shared some photos to B, and then B can directly see those photos within his own client app. A and B used different dropbox accounts.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You have used Core Dropbox API or Sync Dropbox API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, there's no programmatic way to invite people to a shared folder. But you can create share links (like right-click, "Share Dropbox Link" on the desktop). Those links aren't tied to a specific user... anyone who has the link can see the file. So there isn't any sort of notification in Dropbox to the user you're sharing with. You would need to send a notification within your app to the other user giving them the URL.

Comment: Got it, thanks! My boss doesn't want to make it complicated (no backend), so let me to have a look at it to see whether there is a easier way to handle this.